# Forcing jQuery to recognize certain attributes before a fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I have a bunch of `<div class="circle">...</div>` which I plan on animating, as if they were particle effects, into their final positions as they fade in.

In my javascript I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

allCircles = $(".circle");

for (var i = 0; i < allCircles.length; i++) {
    console.log('hello: ' + allCircles[i].offsetTop + ' , ' + allCircles[i].offsetLeft);
}

allThings = $("*");
allThings.fadeIn(2500);

for (var i = 0; i < allCircles.length; i++) {
    console.log('hello: ' + allCircles[i].offsetTop + ' , ' + allCircles[i].offsetLeft);
```

The offsetTop and offsetLeft (defined in a css file) are their final positions. With the for loops I noticed that before the fadeIn, the offsetTop and offsetLeft attributes are all zero-ed. Only after the fadeIn event is triggered does the css offset properties come in effect. Why would jQuery zero out everything before animating its fadeIn?

Comment: can not retrieve offset or dimensins of a hidden element. Has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your circles are `display: none` in your CSS before they're faded in, you're not going to get any position offsets. I would suggest doing `opacity: 0` and using `.animate({opacity: 1})` instead.